# Subnumcases as a part of align

Tags: equations, align, labels, cases

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \underset{\tau \in \mathbb{R}}{\min} \ \tau
\end{align*}
\begin{subnumcases}{\textrm{s.t.} \ \forall w \in {dom} f^*, \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^q: }
    d^\top \lambda + w^\top b - f^*(w) \leq 0 \\
    D^\top \lambda \geq A^\top w \\
    \lambda \geq \mathbf{0}
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

To produce the following:
[image]

I am happy with the result, but I don't feel like I am doing the correct thing. Both of the min term and s.t. term belong to the same optimization problem. When I define the minimization line with align* and the constraints with subnumcases, then there are problems like:

1. A new page can start right after the 'min' part
2. When I use label, ref, then it says Problem (3.2), but actually, the min tau line is not in Problem 3.2
3. In similar but bigger problems, the alignment looks odd

Thus, I will be very happy to hear some suggestions!

Comment: True, this is a part from a big project so I couldn't copy-paste the relevant packages. Now I am fixing it.

Comment: Fixed them all, now working on  \DeclareMathOperator. Do you have any idea about how I can combine the align* term and subcases term? Thank you

Comment: thanls for completing the example (although it doesn't allow anyone to comment on the  `\label` issue which is presumably a problem in an earlier `\begin{problem}` leaking the `\label` information?

Comment: It is very hard to illustrate the label-ref issue for me because I need to give a full page where this problem will be separated due to the issue I mention etc. I will try to also give a convenient example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably just use `cases` but if you definitely want the `subnumcases` layout you could use a `minipage` to keep things together.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,cases}
\DeclareMathOperator\dom{dom}
\begin{document}

using gather
\begin{gather*}
    \min_{\tau \in \mathbb{R}} \tau\\
\shortintertext{s.t.}
\forall w \in \dom f^*, \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^q
\begin{cases}
    d^\top \lambda + w^\top b - f^*(w) \leq 0 \\
    D^\top \lambda \geq A^\top w \\
    \lambda \geq \mathbf{0}
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}


a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\
a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\
a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\
a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\
a\\a\\a

using [\\
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\noindent\[
    \min_{\tau \in \mathbb{R}} \tau\\
\]
s.t.
\begin{subnumcases}
{\forall w \in \dom f^*, \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^q}
    d^\top \lambda + w^\top b - f^*(w) \leq 0 \\
    D^\top \lambda \geq A^\top w \\
    \lambda \geq \mathbf{0}
\end{subnumcases}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose this variant layout, using the facilities of the `optidef` package, dedicated to the layout of optimisation problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}

\begin{document}

    \begin{mini!}
        {\mathclap{\tau\in\mathbb{R}}}{\tau \notag}
        {}{}
        \addConstraint{}{ d^\top \lambda + w^\top b - f^*(w) \leq 0\label{eqa}}
        \addConstraint{\forall w \in \dom f^*, \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^q:\smash{\begin{cases}\\\\\\\end{cases}}\hspace*{-1em}}{D^\top \lambda \geq A^\top w \label{eqb}}
        \addConstraint{}{\lambda \geq \mathbf{0}\label{eqc}}
   \end{mini!}
We can see from \cref{eqa,eqb,eqc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very nice, but also hard :) I will look for the documentation of optidef!

Comment: Also, do you think it is impossible to merge the align* and subnumcases parts of my code?

Comment: I tried to use `subnumcases` as a ‘subenvironment’ once (somewhat like `aligned`), but wasn't able to do it (this doesn't prove it's impossible, though).